# C++ pointer vs C# pointer

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I am an experienced C# developer, and I just started asking myself something.

I've read a lot about differences between C++ and C# in game development.

Almost everyone said that C++ is better in game dev because it can directly access memory through a pointer. As far as I know, C# can also use pointers if the unsafe keycode is used.

So, that means that C# can also directly access memory. And then the question comes again, what is the difference between the C++ pointer and the C# pointer? Is one better then the other? If there are no differences, why would C++ be better than C#?

(I know from my own experience that I've had problems with the C# garbage collection, so I thought that this might be the reason C++ is preferred)

Comment: This is a very tiny thing compared to the other differences between the languages, and environments. Short answer: raw pointers in C# aren’t really different from C++. But that doesn’t really explain anything about the differences between these two. And it’s a very broad thing to explain so it doesn’t fit this site.

Comment: Better and preferred? Those terms are so subjective. C# has some great game engines built for it. Although if I went into game programming, I'd pick C and assembly for sure, but then I'm old-fashioned.

Comment: Have you done any research? [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23557148/1997232).

Comment: @Bathsheba Assembly? Really? But then you'd need to implement EVRYTHING yourself, using all these architecture specific instructions. You'd need to write code for every generation of CPU and GPU of every vendor. (Or accept you cannot use HW acceleration and have a slow game)

Comment: `Almost everyone said that C++ is better because it can directly access memory through a pointer` i nearly spit my coffee out. i mean who is everyone, what do they class as better. What metrics are they using, what are they programming, how long does it take them to develop it, how easy is it for someone to manage and understand their code. how much testing do they do

Comment: I've searched and found that almost every big company uses C/C++ for game development, found nothing about C#

Comment: C++ only has the equivalent of value types.  Treating them like reference types (allocated with `new`) requires using pointers.  This is not necessary in C#, code that uses reference types (declared with the class keyword) automatically use pointers under the hood.  So a large reason for *having* to use pointers in C++ instantly disappears.

Comment: So, that leads me to my final question, is C++ actually better than C# in game dev? Is it worth to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll say that the weak point of C# is that, given a `void*` pointer, you can't always cast it to a `MyStruct*` pointer, and surely as hell you can't cast it to a `MyStruct[]` or a `byte[]` (and the array type is one of the basic types of .NET, and is used pretty much everywhere). This makes interop quite difficult and slow, because often you have to first copy from a `void*` to a newly created `MyStruct[]` just to be able to use the data in .NET.

The alternative clearly is working everywhere with pointers in C# (you can probably do it) and minimize the use of arrays `[]`, but the languages isn't built for that. For example the generic subsystem (`List<T>`) doesn't accept pointers (you can't `List<int*>`). You can clearly use `IntPtr`... but then you have to cast it to `int*` when you need a `int*`... it is a pain.